# Sending additional parameter in autocomplete query via ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Autocomplete code works but Iam not able to filter the output (whisperer records) with actual searching value, because that parameter (d.queryString) is not in the ajax request.

I have this code,
**Textbox**

```
<input type="text" name="CustomerNumber" value="@if (@ViewBag.CustomerNumber != null){@ViewBag.CustomerNumber}" />
```

**Jquery script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("input[name='CustomerNumber']").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetCustomerNames")',
                    data: function (d) {
                        d.queryString = $("input[name='CustomerNumber']").val()
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        // assuming data is a JavaScript array such as
                        // ["one@abc.de", "onf@abc.de","ong@abc.de"]
                        // and not a string
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 3
        });

    });

</script>
```

**.NET Controller**

```
   public JsonResult GetCustomerNames(string searchQuery)
            {
                var autocompleteList = new List<string>();
                using (var db = new DB.APPDBContext())
                {
                    autocompleteList = db.GetAutocompleteList(1, searchQuery).ToList();
                }

                return Json(autocompleteList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

And if i type 3 letters I get all (not filtered) records to the whisperer, because the parameter queryString (actual textbox value) is not send to the controller. Why the queryString parameter is missing in the ajax request ?

Thank you for ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create an object with contents of the textbox:

```
 var queryString = {        
    searchQuery: $("input[name='CustomerNumber']").val()
 }
```

2) Then create an URL using the `$.param` to generate the query string:

```
var url = "@Url.Action("GetCustomerNames")?" + $.param(queryString);
```

3) Use the URL generated in your Ajax method:

```
$("input[name='CustomerNumber']").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'GET',
                url: url,
                success: function (data) {
                    // assuming data is a JavaScript array such as
                    // ["one@abc.de", "onf@abc.de","ong@abc.de"]
                    // and not a string
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! I just used data: {searchQuery: request.term} and it works too :-)